# Powershell to list all Azure AD users and groups

Tags: azure-active-directory

is there a way to list my users and groups in Azure AD?

I've seen there's an "AzureAD" PS module which I've installed, but cant see to get it working.

I've also read a little on Graph API, is this required?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so worked it out.

First had to install the module:
Install-Module AzureAD -Force

Then import it:
Import-Module AzureADPreview

The Connect:
Connect-AzureAD

Now you can run the AzureAD commands:
Get-AzureADUser

Might help others...